# Help me learn to be a Salesforce Developer

Tags: learning

I am a fresher and planning to make my career in Salesforce. I really need help from experts. 
What is the requirements and what should i know to become a salesforce developer?I am currently working as Java developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came into Salesforce from Java. I recommend Salesforce trailhead.
https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en

This is easy way to start with Salesforce, after completing developer and administrator trailhead, you will have solid basic knowledge of Salesforce platform. 
For more advanced knowledge I recommend Force.com Workbook.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook

This teaches you how to build applications on Force.com platform

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en along with http://www.sfdc99.com/ , which is a really helpful website to introduce someone into salesforce.

I would Also recommend Advanced apex Programming as a great book to learn best practices along with this :
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices